# How do I save sheets as PDF from a Shared Workbook via VBA?

Tags: vba, pdf, excel

I have the following VBA code which I call on `ThisWorkbook_Open`, which will check the day and see if there is a sheet for that week (its a timesheet for people to fill in). It sees if the latest week (starting Saturday) is already a valid sheet and if not it knows that the week has ended and to produce a report for that week (by PDF) and create a new sheet for the current week.

```
Sub getFirstDayofWeek()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim summWS As Worksheet
Dim loopSht As Worksheet
Dim thisWeek As String, lastWeek As String
Dim dateExists As Boolean
dateExists = False
Set summWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
thisWeek = Format(Now() - Weekday(Now(), vbSaturday) + 1, "ddmmyy")
lastWeek = Format(Now() - Weekday(Now(), vbSaturday) - 6, "ddmmyy")
For Each loopSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If loopSht.Name = thisWeek Then
dateExists = True
Exit For
End If
Next
If dateExists Then
Debug.Print "Do nothing"
Else
Debug.Print "Do something"

runReport ("\\save\report\here\")

Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets("Summary %")
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Name = thisWeek
ws.Range("A1").Value = Now() - Weekday(Now(), vbSaturday) + 1
summWS.Rows("25:26").Copy
summWS.Rows("25:25").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
summWS.Rows("5:26").Replace What:=lastWeek, Replacement:=thisWeek, LookAt:=xlPart
End If
Sheets(thisWeek).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and the sub doing the saving...

```
Sub runReport(Optional fileString As String = "C:\Temp\")
Dim reportWeek As String, filePath As String

If Right(fileString, 1) <> "\" Then
fileString = fileString & "\"
End If

reportWeek = Format(Now() - Weekday(Now(), vbSaturday) - 6, "ddmmyy")

If Dir(fileString, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
fileString = "\\another\backup\failsafe\path\"
MsgBox "Filepath not found. Will be saved as " & fileString
End If

filePath = fileString & "Times PDF - " & reportWeek & ".pdf"
Sheets(Array("Summary", "Summary %", reportWeek)).Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filePath, 57
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I have found that when the workbook is shared, I get a `1004: Method 'SaveAs' or object '_Workbook' failed` error on opening, however if I unshare the workbook then it works fine. Obviously as well, commenting out the `runReport` line also makes it work fine.

The workbook needs to be shared (as its a timesheet used by a number of people) so removing sharing isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for this. Not exactly solving why it doesn't work in this instance, but I briefly unshare the workbook in the VBA while I save the PDF and then re-enable the share immediately afterwards.

Not ideal and not sure if any issues may be caused if someone else has it open at that precise time, but it works for my needs (as there's only a handful of us use this and we are all within shouting distance of each other)